# Highcharts Heatmap xAxis tick alignment

Tags: highcharts

The issue is that the x-axis tick marks appear off center for every other cell. I want them to be centered.

Here is my fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/udeleng/ry10Lc6q/6/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "heatmap",
    "zoomType": "x",
    "panning": true,
    "panKey": "shift"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": null
  },
  "colorAxis": {
    "stops": [
      [0, "#3060cf"],
      [0.5,"#fffbbc"],
      [0.9,"#c4463a"]
    ]
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "lineColor": "#ffffff",
    "labelsx": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "style": {
        "color": "#6e6e70"
      }
    },
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "cropThreshold": 100000,
      "turboThreshold": 0
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "tooltip": {
        "headerFormat": "",
        "pointFormat": "{point.value}"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1493622000000,
          "y": 0,
          "value": 1.4
        },
        {
          "x": 1493622000000,
          "y": 1,
          "value": 0.9
        },
        ...
      ],
      "colsize": 86400000
    }
  ]
});
```

If instead using series.data array property, I use the CSV option (with the data module) to add that data, then the ticks are centered:

https://jsfiddle.net/udeleng/xetj9Lds/4/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "heatmap",
    "zoomType": "x",
    "panning": true,
    "panKey": "shift"
  },
  data: {
    firstRowAsNames: false,
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
  },
  "title": {
    "text": null
  },
  "colorAxis": {
    "stops": [
      [0, "#3060cf"],
      [0.5,"#fffbbc"],
      [0.9,"#c4463a"]
    ]
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "lineColor": "#ffffff",
    "labelsx": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "style": {
        "color": "#6e6e70"
      }
    },
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "cropThreshold": 100000,
      "turboThreshold": 0
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "tooltip": {
        "headerFormat": "",
        "pointFormat": "{point.value}"
      },
      "colsize": 86400000
    }
  ]
});
```

I would prefer no to have to figure out tick placement, spacing, or any of that each time, as it seems to work correctly when using csv.

I can't use CSV because I need to associated additonal meta-data for each data point, which the series.data array of objects allows for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different `x` values. Please compare:

```
console.log(new Date(1493622000000));
console.log(new Date('2017-05-01'));
```

Results:

```
Mon May 01 2017 09:00:00 GMT+0200
Mon May 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k84sqmeh/

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. I see now that Highcharts uses UTC by default. The string time 2017-05-01 was converted to a proper UTC timestamp, but my timestamp, in the first demo, was not based on UTC, but on local time, which made it GMT-07:00 DST. I suppose that's the reason why the tick mark was offset left.